# How to find name of dependencies which cause make to build

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using GNU MAKE tool for building my embedded C project. Whenever I build using make command it always rebuild entire project even though there is no change.

Is there any way I can find which dependencies files are causing make to rebuild.

Comment: You can try invoking Make for particular targets (other than the default) to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

`make -d` shows some of the internal workings of make.  It is a lot of data, though, but it usually allows one to pinpoint why the rebuilds happen.

Comment: you can do `make --debug=v` for a bit quiter output.  the `b` won't show you dependency tracking, so you can't really use that.

Comment: If you are not using _make_'s built-in pattern rules, invoke _make_ with `make -Rr -d`. This considerably shortens the debug output.